# My robots.txt file is not reflecting the new content

Tags: wordpress, robots.txt

I have uploaded a new robots.txt file on my cpanel in the public_html directory, but when I browse it through url like www.mydomian.com/robots.txt, its not showing the changes and not refreshing the new content, I have rechecked everything, I can see the chnges when mnully opening the file plese help?? I also cleared cache.

Comment: Patience is the key.

Answer (score 0):

All WordPress installs have a virtual robots.txt file by default but it should be replaced by your robot.txt file.

Do you use a SEO plugin?